# Camera storage perms in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, permissions, camera

I'm trying to create an auto-backup app in which all photos taken from the Camera will be uploaded to Cloudinary.

Using Android Device Monitor, I found that the storage location for Camera images in my Android Studio is "/storage/0804-0A1C/DCIM/Camera" as shown below:

[ADM screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4mnW.png)

However, I am unable to read from this directory because of permissions(?). I made sure to add WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to the manifest but canRead() returns false. What can I do to gain access with my code?

```
class UploadPhotos implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
        System.out.println("--------dir " + storageDir + " " + storageDir.canRead());
        String[] files = storageDir.list();
        if (files != null) {
            System.out.println("code does not get this far, files == null");
            for (String file : files) {
                if (new File(storageDir + file).isDirectory()) {
                    String[] subFiles = new File(storageDir + file).list();
                    for (int i = 0; i < subFiles.length; i++) {
                        if (new File(subFiles[i]).isFile()) {
                            uploadFile(new File(subFiles[i]));
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    uploadFile(new File(file));
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Android are you running on? What is your `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: @CommonsWare Running Marshmellow, targetSdkVersion = 23

Comment: @CommonsWare The solution in the thread you referenced worked (in combination with setReadable(true)). Thanks!